# Webform calculator (I need to delay the result)

Tags: javascript, webforms

https://www.drupal.org/project/webform_calculator

Hello, is there a way to delay the calculation for performance purpose ?
The problem is that I have a TON of formulas being calculated every time I type inside the inputs, and this is making the whole thing very SLOW.

**I need something like: "Wait 2 seconds after keyup and mouseup > show formula results"**

Comment: you could try adding a `.delay(2000)` in line 28,29,30 in [webform_calculator.js](http://cgit.drupalcode.org/webform_calculator/tree/webform_calculator.js). Try like `.unbind('keyup', handler).delay(2000).bind('keyup', handler)`

Comment: doesn't work :(

Answer (score 1):

Well, this is how I managed to delay the calculation results in
[webform_calculator.js](http://cgit.drupalcode.org/webform_calculator/tree/webform_calculator.js)
line 12, 13, 14

```
setTimeout(function(){
  Drupal.webformCalculator.evaluateAllFormulas();
}, 3000);
```